# How to know where the temporary files that have arrived from Postman are saved

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I am using Postman and Laravel.
From a Postman request I receive a file.
I don't know where I can find that file.

I used:

```
$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]

sys_get_temp_dir()

getRealPath()
```

All those methods confirm that the path is C:\wamp64\tmp\phpD3D.tmp

The weird thing is that the file is not named like that.

The ultimate goal is to move that temporary file to a specific path.

To move the file I am using:

```
Storage::move($path_name, 'diba/wifis/3/abc.gz');
```

Taking into account that $path_name is the result of the function getRealPath() what is the next value C:\wamp64\tmp\phpD3D.tmp

When the move function is going to be executed, it tells me that it has not found the file.

The file is not in the right place, I don't know if someone can help me.

First because it is not called the same as the name that I indicate in postman and second where it saves the file.

Thanks

Comment: _"First because it is not called the same as the name that I indicate in postman"_ - the name the client sends, is not the name PHP uses to temporarily store the file. The name the client provided, would be contained in `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`

Comment: Thank you very much!! Could you tell me where I can find the file?

Comment: Most likely exactly there, where PHP told you it was - what reason should it have to lie to you about this? _"it tells me that it has not found the file"_ - please quote the exact error message.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as Laravel as well, then I'm going to assume you're using it. You should handle file uploads through the Request facade instead of `$_FILES`. You can find documentation for that here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('diba/wifis/3/abc.gz', $request->file);
```